# REST - getting Response with a delay

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I want to get Response with a delay and using for it
`future.get(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. I get response almost immediately but the Eclipse process does not finish for aboute a minute or similair. It looks like memory leak.

So, is it a proper way to get Response with a delay? And why it takes too much time to finish the process?

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature httpFeature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("admin", "admin");
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(httpFeature);
Future<Response> future = client.target(webServiceURI).request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).async().get();
Response response = null;
try {
    response = future.get(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
Object result = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(result);
client.close();
```

Comment: According to the Javadoc, get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) `Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.`. So if the future completes before, you will get the result immediatly, otherwise a TimeoutException will be thrown. One option here could be to use a Thread.sleep() but this approach seems tricky. Would you mind explaining why you need to wait 1 sec ?

Comment: @LouisF. The reason I doing so is because the server process may be too long to complete and the `TimeoutException ` will be thrown in this case so this task may be considered as `not completed`. In other words, I want to consider the request which is running longer then particular time like not succesfull.

Comment: What do you mean by considered as not completed. You mean that if you call `isDone()`on the future, then the result will be false ?

Comment: @LouisF. I mean it's just a condition of the task to consider a request like `not completed` if task will not complete in a given time. But for now it's more interesting why yet it takes long time to finish the process...

Comment: What happens if you close the `Response` (which you should always do anyway)?. Also consider that `getEntity()` doesn't consume the input stream. What you want is `readEntity(String.class)` to get the String entity. This consumes the input stream. If you look at the javadoc for [`Response.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#close--), it says that `Response`s where the input stream is not consumed nor closed, could lead to memory leaks. This _might_ be the problem

Comment: @peeskillet wel, maybe. I recently switched to the server asinc implementation and it seem that the problem does no apper anymore.